# Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'doSum' from 'Sum' (G:\firstpy\Sum.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python files in one folder named firstpy. But when I am trying to import a function of python file named Sum then it gives me the error mentioned in question. The two files are:

Sum.py:

```
class Sum:
        def doSum(a,b):
        print(a+b)
```

Calculator.py:

```
from Sum import doSum

class Calculator:

    doSum(4,5)
```

Please tell me what the error is and the solutions out there are not working for me.

Comment: Why are you making classes everywhere?

Comment: I am just learning python, so I am trying to import one module into another.

Comment: This isn't Java, you don't have to create tons of classes. When you `import Sum`, the file called `Sum.py` is imported. Any functions defined in a class are _not_ imported separately from that class.

Comment: So how to import that function?

Comment: You can't import a function from a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the method inside a class the "Sum" class, so you have to import the class, instantiate it and then you can use the method (from the class).

If you want to import only the method you have to declare it OUT of the class.

Sum.py:

```
#class with methods
class Sum:
    def class_method(self):
         print("dostuff")

#only a method
def doSum(a,b):
    print(a+b)
```

Comment: I have got your instantiate way but will you please show me how can i declare the method outside of a class? Wouldn't it be an indentation error?

Comment: The point is that you don't need classes in python to have methods, look at the edit to see the sample code

Answer (score 1):

Use pure function instead of class or make this function static:

in Sum.py

```
def do_sum(a, b):
    #  your code
```

Then you can import it like this: `from Sum import do_sum`.
Or try this:

```
class Sum:
    @staticmethod
    def do_sum(a, b):
        #  your code
```

import: `from Sum import Sum` and call: `Sum.do_sum(args)`.

If you still want to use class for it, then in your Calculator.py:

```
from Sum import Sum


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = Sum()

    def calculate(self, a, b):
        return self.sum.do_sum(a, b)
```

Btw, you don't have to name your modules with a capital letter like in Java. Also, there is slightly another name conventions - not camel case, but snake case (doSum -> do_sum)